# DVI-D to VGA adapter doesn't seem to work

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have got two DVI-D DualLink Male to VGA female adapters and a Graphics card with with HDMI, VGA and two DVI-D outputs. When I plug my VGA monitors into the adapters then into the video card, they don't display a picture). But the card recognizes, at least one of them as an analog display and knows the names of both displays, so something must be working. Is there anything I can do?

System:
    Asus GTX 650ti DCU2 (for secondary displays) (the one I'm trying to plug these adapters into)
    EVGA GTX 970 SSC (for primary display)
    Sabertooth Z77
    i7 3770k
    8GB RAM
    1200w PSU

Working Config: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeykN.png
Desired Config:        "  "       /zpYU8nj.png

Displays 4 and 2 are the same monitor for some reason there is two. Screenshot of the config below:
[image]

Info from the seller of the adapters; listing [is here](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/300745033049):

> The adapter to the DVI connector from your video card and convert it
>   to VGA connector for setting up dual monitors / projectors. Provide
>   people who want to use the dual monitors for their work/game
>   environment. If your individual Graphic video card  has dual output
>   ports,  one VGA output and one DVI-D output (do not support on-board
>   DVI-D output), then you can simply attach and make it works.
>
> - Gold plated PIN
> - One 15 pin male to Female VGA connector
> - One 25 pin DVI-D male connector on the other side
> - Size: 4.3 x 4 x 1.5cm (LxWxH)

[image]

And yes I could plug a monitor into the VGA port and the other to the DVI-I adapter on the other GPU, but I want this to work for future plans.

Comment: Passive DVI-I to VGA adapters are not converting anything, the video cards (that have it) already have VGA available at that port, the adapter just connects it. The video card your using model and whom manufactured it is important? Then they only supply this once , usually on the first or primary DVI-I connection. if they already supply a VGA port seperate it does not seem likely they would also supply it at the DVI point. What is the video card, and what are the actual specs DVI-I or are they DVI-D, and DualLink is only digital, so that also is not an indication of a analog VGA signal.

Comment: Looking at the link to e-bay the use of the word "converter" is not accurate, it would be concidered only an "adapter" a converter could actually convert the digital to VGA, cost more and are usually bigger, and require power from somewhere. Converters come in bad, barely watchable and really expencive :-) If there is any way to go all digital you would certannly prefer that.

Comment: Yes it was a misleading listing, probably can't send it back, I will just give the seller negative feedback...

Comment: This adapter is basically a fraud and should *never* work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a passive adaptor. It converts a *DVI-I* into a analogue VGA port. More precisely, it *breaks out* the analogue portions of a DVI-I connector. It will not work in a proper DVI-D port (or an improper one with a DVI-I socket).

To actually convert DVI-D (or any real digital out - displayport, hdmi ect) to VGA you need an *active* adaptor.

If its a DVI-I port, something else is wrong.

Comment: Yes. Dosen't mean its correct.

Comment: Okay. I thought there might be a chance since even though it was plugged into the DVI-D port, the system still realised it was VGA. I thought it might be able to channel the analog signal to the DVI-D port.. I'll get a DVI-D to HDMI + HDMI to VGA adapter for about $11. Rather then a DVI-D to VGA for $50. Don't suppose you know why the price is so different if they do the exact same thing?  Thanks for the extra info anyways.

Comment: They do not do the same thing. HDMI is a digital signal just like DVI is (VGA is instead analog) DVI to HDMI is more or less an adaption also, not a conversion. just as the DVI is an uncompressed digital streaming output, HDMI inputs can also take and display an uncompressed digital streaming input of the same type. There can be cases where a HDMI TV does not work as expected with the computers DVI signal, but in most cases it will work fine to adapt the DVI to HDMI, or even from HDMI (video card output) to DVI input (on a monitor).  If you have choices of HDMI or VGA, you would prefer HDMI.

Comment: With other notes that sometimes adapting DVI&HDMI (in both directions) can require adjusting settings properly on both the computer side, and the TV or Monitor side, to get everything set perfectally.

Comment: Always worth checking if they are passive or active

Comment: The whole point of a DVI-D port is that there *is* no analogue signal to "channel". You must use a DVI-I port or DVI-A port for there to be anything to channel.

Answer (score 3):

Check this and see the picture on he right: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Digital

The DVI connector on a device is given one of three names, depending on which signals it implements:

```
DVI-I (integrated, combines digital and analog in the same connector; digital may be single or dual link)
DVI-D (digital only, single link or dual link)
DVI-A (analog only)
```

So, to receive an analogue signal there has to be a DVI-I or DVI-A output. DVI-D does not produce this, so VGA is not within this one.